# Empty POST /users Request BY OKTA server, causes internal server error

Tags: json, mongodb, okta, okta-api, scim

I am trying to use OKTA provisioning using SCIM endpoint for getting data from OKTA to my local DataBase.

So, I have created scim endpoint for my SCIM 2.0 Test App (OAuth Bearer Token) using NODE.js and MongoDB as Database. When I assign new User to this Application OKTA provisioning server send the GET request which responded with expected output.

So, than OKTA server sends the POST request with /users . But it has empty body in it instead of containing valid JSON. And so my scim endpoint responds with an error and OKTA shows error 500. So, let me know in which format/part (like BODY, PARAMETERS) OKTA server might be sending USER JSON to create new user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not an empty request, 
OKTA uses `application/scim+json` as `content-type`, configure your server to accept the header and process it further to find the req body content.

Comment: For anyone coming back to this post, for ExpressJS if you use `body-parser`, you can allow this by setting `bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/scim+json' })`

Comment: or `type: ['application/json', 'application/scim+json']` :D

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using a tool like [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com/) or [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to help you debug your SCIM server.

As a starting point, I suggest using [Okta's example SCIM server](https://developer.okta.com/standards/SCIM/#appendix-using-the-example-scim-server), which is [written in Python and available on GitHub](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-scim-beta).

In your particular case, make sure that you are responding to the GET request to /Users with an empty response. The GET request is made first to check if the user already exists on your system.

That said, I strongly recommend that you use [Okta's set of Runscope tests](https://developer.okta.com/standards/SCIM/#test-your-scim-server) to develop your Node.js SCIM implementation. The Runscope test suite is quite exhaustive and will help you make sure that you have implemented the parts of SCIM that you need to implement to work with Okta.

Learn more about Okta's test suite here: https://developer.okta.com/standards/SCIM/#test-your-scim-server

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have found the another appropriate solution @joel

Answer (score -2):

OKTA server is not sending the schema in BODY of POST call. It actually using Event-Driven Programming, So, I had to use req.on('data', callback). and schema will be stored in data.